# Match first and last character(s) of any word

Tags: windows-7, regex, sublime-text-3, text-editing, characters

I searched a lot but didn't find any help.

I want to use a regex for matching first (one or more) and last characters (one or more) of any word, not only find but it has to match with first and last characters of any word.

example:

- reading
- repairing

So the regex has to match with only "re" and "ing, not with "ad" or "pair". 
And the regex has to match with "re" and "ing" in same time (in the same word), not separately. So output has to be like that (I did bold them):

- **re**ad**ing**
- **re**pair**ing**

I am not a coder. I am just redacting/proofreading a very huge text in Sublime Text 3 editor on Windows 7.

Edit:
Solved! Thank you very much Bo L. Your advice is working. I wrote in find box \b(re)(\S*)(ing)\b and wrote in replace $2 and it is working. You did very different fix but it is ok now :)

Comment: There are plenty of [Regular Expression "Cheat Sheets"](https://www.google.com/search?q=regex+cheat+sheet) out there, and more than a few [Regular Expression Tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=regex+tutorial). Please explain what you don't understand and what you've tried - we're not a code-writing service.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @harrymc (1) The question says “Windows 7”. (2) The question is *about* Sublime Text 3. Would the answer for Sublime Text 3 on Linux be different from the answer for Sublime Text 3 on Windows?

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  As you as aware, you have accidentally created two accounts.  This will interfere with commenting, editing your own posts, and accepting an answer.  You should use the [contact form](/contact) and select ‘‘I need to merge user profiles’’ to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, they are https://superuser.com/users/997906/user997906 and https://superuser.com/users/998023/orkacan.  You’ll then be able to [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your objective? What does 'not [matching] with "ad" or "pair"' mean to you?
Are you looking for a pattern that can match words that begin with 're' and end with 'ing', irrespective of what is in between?

If so, this could be a helpful pattern:

```
\b(re)\S*(ing)\b
```

'\b' defines word boundaries and '\S*' allows any number of non-whitespace characters in between 're' and 'ing' (0 or more, so technically "reing" will match).
You can replace the '\S' as needed if you have a stricter requirement for what can make up words (perhaps '(a-zA-Z)' for any letter, or '\w' for letters, numbers, and underscores?)

Edit:

If you are looking to replace affixes while preserving the original word, you can use a slightly modified pattern:

```
\b(re)(\S*)(ing)\b
```

and use this pattern in Sublime Text's "replace with" field:

```
un$2ed
```

To change "repairing" to "unpaired", for example. $2 references the "pair" in "repairing" and allows you to preserve it in the replacement value.

It will still match with "reading" however, so you will have to manually go through each match to confirm you are not creating gibberish word like "reading" into "unaded". I'm not a regex expert, but to automate that is beyond regex alone IME.

Comment: Thank Bo L. but it doesnt work for me. I wrote the sample in my question. Let me explain more clearly. There are tons words in my text which starts with "re" (without quotes) and ends with "ing". For example, "repairing", "reacting"... I want to delete or replace with another characters the "re" and "ing". But also i dont want to delete all of re and ing because i only want to replace/delete them if they are in affix position. So, "reading" as you know, "re" of "reading" is not an affix, it is in built already. That's why i dont want to delete all "re" and "ing".

Comment: Consequently, output of regex has to be like that: "reading" "repairing" should match only with re and ing, not with "ad" or "pair".

Comment: I've tried your regex formula but it matched with exact word of "reading"

Comment: @Orkacan I've updated the solution with your new info, hopefully that's what you're looking for.